# Angular2 implementing a scale component

Tags: angular

I want to build a component which acts as a scale and parameters for the scale could be numeric or textual. See mockup:

[image]

How can I realize such a component, especially HTML and css considering parameters can be different each time use this component?

Comment: didnt understand your question! Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is somehow vague, here are some guidelines of a direction I used to create a similar component for a wizard navigation header:

- Avoid using only CSS because of a dynamic number of elements
- Use the component HTML to create a table your the component
- There will be N columns (where N is the number of discreet values you have)
- Use a table row of N cells to define the texts (e.g. your ranges or names), and center-align the texts
- Use another table row of cells to define the lines (e.g. using a border on those cells)
- Optionally use another table row for the icons you have there, if you need that
- In the end, all things are aligned to the center, and the lines should slightly extend away from the first and last texts
- The component template will be a combination of `ngFor` iterating over the values you have there

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't think that I could use table in this case. I was only concerned whether I really should create a component or just handle everything with html and css as I had a feeling that if not in html I will write enough code in ts file.